# How to change color at beamer class using Luebeck theme and split outertheme?

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I'm using the beamer class together with Luebeck theme and split outertheme. I already managed to adjust to color of the basic structure, if I use a dark color everything is fine, but now I have to use yellow.

Here's a example of my code:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{}{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet} %Helvetica Font
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\useoutertheme{split}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\definecolor{RVS}{RGB}{251,234,12}
\definecolor{Grey}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=Grey, fg=RVS}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=black}
```

I managed to adjust to color of the title and the headings but I still need to change to color of the text on the TOC page and the TOC at the top provided by split. I want to do the subchapters on the top right in black for better contrast when using the yellow structure.

I hope that someone can help me!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: a list of [beamercolors](http://pastebin.com/nK3BWG5v) might help.

Comment: Without a full MWE, this is 'unclear'.